# Programme is terminating in c++;

Tags: c++

I have written the code which will print the slope from the coordinates of a line and then print it. but when I give input, my code is terminating. what is the problem?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x1,y1,x2,y2,m;

    cin>>x1>>y1>>x2>>y2;

    m=(y1-y2)/(x1-x2);

    cout<<m;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h/31816096#31816096

Comment: What is your input? Why don't you check that the input could really be read?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of input?

Comment: also input is not taking.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058)

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5910058)

Comment: sample input  0 0 0 1

Comment: With that sample input you end up dividing by zero --> KaBoom!

Comment: ok! i got it thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is probably here `m=(y1-y2)/(x1-x2);`. When `x1==x2` you have division by zero, please add some checks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding more corner tests, also note when `x1` is equal to `x2` you will face division by zero error, so you should modify your program with `if` statement to check that they are not equal.

so you should add this to your code:

```
if(x1==x2){
  cout<<"Error division by zero"<<endl;
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tested your code using [c++ compiler online](https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_gcc) and it worked.

You may have a compiler error or something else.

Comment: The program does *not* work for all input. It's trivial to provide input that causes it to divide by zero. That's not what I would call a "working" program.

Comment: Not handling extreme cases does not mean the program is not working. The question didn't tell about the input that makes the program terminate. I also said that the error can be something else (for example, input), but it generally works.

Comment: Passing two identical numbers to something that subtracts them and then does a division is hardly an *extreme* case.